# Download a file with machine-readable progress output

Tags: linux, download

I need a (linux) program that can download from a HTTP (or optionally FTP) source, and output its progress to the terminal, in a machine-readable form.

What I mean by this is I would like it to NOT use a progress bar, but output progress as a percentage (or other number), one line at a time.

As far as I know, both `wget` and `curl` don't support this.

Comment: Why not use a library that has progress reporting built-in?

Comment: I'm pretty sure wget supports this, check the man page.

Comment: @Ignacio I'd like to put as little as possible irrelevant content in the question, but here's the explanation: I'm writing a tool that SSHs into a remote server and needs to download a file there. While doing this, I need the progress information to be displayed in a web application. So using a library is not the way to go, as I don't want to install software on said remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). The percentage is already there.

PS. Also, this isn't strictly programming related..

Comment: Hmm, you're actually right. If `wget`'s stdout is not a terminal, it does write the progress info in a pretty easily parsable way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use curl with PipeViewer (http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want another script or application to read the progress and do something with it, yes? If this is the case, then I'd suggest using libcurl in that application/script to do the downloading. You'll be able to easily process the progress and do whatever you want with it. This is far easier than trying to parse output from wget or curl.

The progress bar from curl and wget can be parsed, just ignore the bar itself and extract the % done, time left, data downloaded, and whatever metrics you want. The bar is overwritten using special control characters. When parsed by another application, you will see many \r's and \b's.